# Resize UICollectionView bounds to fit the cells using Storyboard + Auto Layout

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I have a **UICollectionView** inside a view section with constrains to autosize depending on screen size.

[**UICollectionView** in Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzK2J.png)

The code for my **UICollectionView**

```
let answerArray = ["ABC", "AB", "AD", ".", "ABC", "AB", "AD", ".", "ABC", "AB", "AD", ".", "ABC", "AB", "AD", ".", "ABC", "AB", "AD", ".", "ABC", "AB", "AD", ".", "ABC", "AB", "AD", ".", "ABC", "AB", "AD", ".", "ABC", "AB", "AD", ".", "ABC", "AB", "AD", "."]
var cellMarginSize = 16

//MARK: - Data source Required Functions
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 40
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collection_View.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ItemCell", for: indexPath) as! ItemCell
    cell.setData(qNumber: indexPath.row + 1, qAnswer: answerArray[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 50, height: 20)
}


//MARK: - Results IBs and Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var view_TopBar: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var view_BottomBar: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var label_SeriesName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var label_SeriesDate: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var collection_View: UICollectionView!



//MARK: - Loading ---------------------------------------------------------------------
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Collection View Delegates
    self.collection_View.isScrollEnabled = false
    self.collection_View.delegate = self
    self.collection_View.dataSource = self

    //Register the Cell
    self.collection_View.register(UINib(nibName: "ItemCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ItemCell")

    //Setup GridView
    self.setupGridView()
}

//MARK: - Setup the Grid View
func setupGridView() {
    let flow = collection_View?.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    flow.minimumInteritemSpacing = CGFloat(self.cellMarginSize)
    flow.minimumLineSpacing = CGFloat(self.cellMarginSize)
    //flow.collectionViewContentSize
}
```

As you can see, i have a fix number of cells (40) and a fix cell widht = 50 and height = 20

This is what i get when i run the app:

[Cells does not fit the dimensions of **UICollectionView** frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Beno.png)

I don't want to allow scrolling/paging in the UICollectionView, so I did disable them.

What I want to achieve, is to make the UICollectionView's frame/bounds to auto resize to fit all the cells.

Or in other words, make all the cells fit inside the parent view of the UICollectionView with equal horizontal and vertical spacing no mater what is the wight and height of the parent view (like GridView in android).

Any help would be really appreciated!
Thank you.

Comment: play around with this function. func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath

Comment: I need the size of the items to be exactly (widht = 50 and height = 20)

Comment: can anyone help on this please??